# How to make likes on a post show without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Dont understand how to see likes on posts without refreshing the page. Sending the request to backend and receiving the response seems fine, posts getting liked and unliked, but to see the likes i need to reload the page and im having a hard time understanding what to do now. Still learning how everything works.

here is the backend code

```
async likePost(req, res) {
    try {
      const post = await Post.findOne({ where: { id: req.params.id } });
      const alreadyLiked = await Likes.findOne({ where: { post_id: post.id, user_id: req.session.user.id } });
      if (!alreadyLiked) {
        const like = await Likes.create({ post_id: post.id, user_id: req.session.user.id });
        console.log('post liked');
        res.json({ like });
      } else {
        await Likes.destroy({ where: { post_id: post.id, user_id: req.session.user.id } });
        console.log('post unliked');
        res.sendStatus(200);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.sendStatus(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  }
```

here is the likeSlice

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  likes: []
}

export const upvotePost = createAsyncThunk(
  'likes/upvotePost',
  async (id, { rejectWithValue, dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`/posts/${id}/likes`);
      dispatch(addLike(response.data.like))
    } catch (error) {
      rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
)

export const likeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'likes',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addLike: (state, action) => {
      state.likes.push(action.payload);
    }
  }
})

const { addLike } = likeSlice.actions;
export default likeSlice.reducer;
```

here is the post code

```
const OnePost = () => {

  const post = useSelector(state => state.post.post_id);
  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);
  console.log('post', post);
  
 

  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const num = post.likedBy?.length
  console.log('num', num);
  const [like, setLike] = useState(num)
  console.log('like--->', like);
  


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOnePost(id))
  }, [like])

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const openUserPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(getOneUser(post.user_id))
  }


  const likePostHandler = () => {
    // if (post.likedBy?.map(el => el.Likes.user_id == user.id)) {
    //   setLike(prev => prev - 1)
      dispatch(upvotePost(id))
    // } else {
    //   setLike(prev => prev + 1)
    //   dispatch(upvotePost(id))
    // }
  }

  const avatar = `http://localhost:3001${post.userAvatar}`
  const createdAt = new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleString(undefined, { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
  const comments = useSelector(state => state.comment.comments);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPostComments(id));
  }, [])


  return (
    <>

      <div className='one-post__container'>
        <div className='one-post'>
          <div className='one-post__info'>
            <div className='one-post__info__head'>
              <div onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
                <ArrowBackIcon className='one-post__back__arrow' />
              </div>
              <span className='profile__name'>
                <h3>Tweet</h3>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className='one-post__info__mid'>
              <Link to={`/user/${post.userId}`} className='one-post__link'>
                <div className='one-post__name' onClick={openUserPageHandler}>
                  <img src={post.userAvatar ? avatar : default_avatar} alt='' className='one-post__profile__avatar' />
                  <h4 className='one-post__user__name'>{post.userName}</h4>
                </div>
              </Link>
              <div className='one-post__options'>
                <MoreHoriz />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className='one-post__body'>{post.text}</div>
            <div className='one-post__footer'>
              <div className='one-post__time'>{createdAt}</div>
              <div className='one-post__icons'>
                <div className='one-post__icons__options'>
                  <ChatBubbleOutline fontSize='small' />
                </div>
                <div className='one-post__icons__options'>
                  <FavoriteBorderOutlined fontSize='small' onClick={likePostHandler} />
                  {like > 0 ? like : null}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

and here is how the post looks like
[post in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5ARJ.png)

best i could try was putting likedBy array.length in useState but it was always undefined, and if it managed to appear for some reason it was not working properly

Answer (score 0):

got it working 95% of the time

other 5% my like goes beyond and adds or removes an extra like or two (if i keep clicking) until it stops and thinks for a second and then goes back to correct value

```
const OnePost = () => {

  const post = useSelector(state => state.post.post_id);
  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);

  const postLikes = post.likedBy?.length;
  const alreadyLiked = post.likedBy?.map(el => el.Likes.user_id).includes(user.id);
  const [likes, setLikes] = useState(postLikes);
  const [isLiked, setIsLiked] = useState(alreadyLiked);

  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const openUserPageHandler = () => {
    dispatch(getOneUser(post.user_id))
  }

  const likePostHandler = () => {
    if (alreadyLiked) {
      setLikes(prev => prev - 1);
      setIsLiked(false)
      dispatch(upvotePost(id));
    } else {
      setLikes(prev => prev + 1);
      setIsLiked(true)
      dispatch(upvotePost(id))
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOnePost(id))
    console.log('likes changed');
  }, [likes])

  useEffect(() => {
    setLikes(postLikes)
    setIsLiked(alreadyLiked)
    console.log('set likes');
  }, [postLikes, alreadyLiked])

  const avatar = `http://localhost:3001${post.userAvatar}`
  const createdAt = new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleString(undefined, { day: 'numeric', month: 'short', year: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
  const comments = useSelector(state => state.comment.comments);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPostComments(id));
  }, [])


  return (
    <>

      <div className='one-post__container'>
        <div className='one-post'>
          <div className='one-post__info'>
            <div className='one-post__info__head'>
              <div onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>
                <ArrowBackIcon className='one-post__back__arrow' />
              </div>
              <span className='profile__name'>
                <h3>Tweet</h3>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className='one-post__info__mid'>
              <Link to={`/user/${post.userId}`} className='one-post__link'>
                <div className='one-post__name' onClick={openUserPageHandler}>
                  <img src={post.userAvatar ? avatar : default_avatar} alt='' className='one-post__profile__avatar' />
                  <h4 className='one-post__user__name'>{post.userName}</h4>
                </div>
              </Link>
              <div className='one-post__options'>
                <MoreHoriz />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className='one-post__body'>{post.text}</div>
            <div className='one-post__footer'>
              <div className='one-post__time'>{createdAt}</div>
              <div className='one-post__icons'>
                <div className='one-post__icons__options'>
                  <ChatBubbleOutline fontSize='small' />
                </div>
                <div className={isLiked ? 'heart active' : 'heart'}>
                  <FavoriteBorderOutlined fontSize='small' onClick={likePostHandler} />
                  {likes > 0 ? likes : null}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <CommentForm />
        <ul className='comments__list'>
          {comments.map((el) => (
            <li key={el.id}>
              <Comment
                id={el.id}
                text={el.text}
                createdAt={el.createdAt}
                userId={el.User?.id}
                userName={el.User?.name}
                userAvatar={el.User?.avatar}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a performant social network, you can follow a common approach used by many platforms. When a user performs an action, such as liking a post, you can send a request to the backend and use React.useState to update the value of liked show and add some style if you want. This way, the user who performed the action will be notified about their action. Additionally, when another user logs in, they will be able to see the likes made by other users because the updated data is fetched. Twitter implements this behavior effectively.

there is another approach, Socket.io can be utilized to send real-time updates to users when another user performs an action, such as liking a post. When a user likes a post, you can send an event via Socket.io to the server, which will then broadcast this information to all other connected users. As a result, other users will receive this real-time update and be able to see the actions performed by other users without needing to refresh the page.
[check the documentation of socket.io](https://socket.io/how-to/use-with-react)

Comment: "When a user performs an action" how can the front-end know if someone other than the current user performs an action? Are you referring to polling or websockets? Also, why are you making assumptions about the back-end, afaik Socket.io is a websocket wrapper for node, would it not make sense to preface that "approach" with "If you are using node..."? Please edit your answer to be more concise and specifik and also add formatting to your code.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, use api calls together with useState. Here's an example with useMutation  (from Tanstack Query (react query)):

```
const likeCommentMutation = useMutation({
    mutationFn: (comment_id) => {
      likeComment(comment_id);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      setLiked((current) => !current);
      if (liked) {
        setLikes((current) => {
          return current - 1;
        });
      } else {
        setLikes((current) => {
          return current + 1;
        });
      }
    },
    onError: () => {
      //error handling
      );
    },
  });

  const onLikedHandler = () => {
    likeCommentMutation.mutate(reply.id);
  };
```

And "like" button can be like this:

```
   <button
          onClick={onLikedHandler}
          disabled={!user_id}
          className="material-symbols-outlined"
        >
          {!liked ? "favorite" : "heart_check"}
          <span className={classes.likes_num}>{likes}</span>
        </button>
```